# How to open files in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I want to open any file like png, jpeg, pdf, doc from local system in cordova. How can I open it there is available any plugin for this. I already tried File Opener plugin but I can't open it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I recently had the same issue, where as I was generating a PDF and tried to open it on either iOS or Android. Maybe you can took a look at this, Ghandi (user who gave the correct answer) has given me a lot of tips on this matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792989/render-pdf-from-html-and-show-it

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your valuable time. Let me check ie

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft This should get you started as Jorrex suggested - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Thank you so much. @Gandhi Can we open PDF file in our application without open in default app of device.

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft Ya. Thats what file opener plugin does actually by providing you the option to select which application to open

Comment: But I want to open PDF in my Application means With my App header footer. and In content part PDF will display something like this.

Comment: How are you implementing the plugin? Is this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022359/load-pdf-from-filesystem-into-an-ionic-cordova-android-pdf-js-application