# Phonegap - How to emailComposer to compose email?

Tags: android, cordova, email, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am building app on phonegap with cordova and framework7. I want to compose email on android phone through Email Composer. 
I try to use this plugin.

```
'com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer'
```

https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer

Here is my code.

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function (callback) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(callback));
}, 'Subject', 'body', ['dummy@gmail.com'], null, null, true, path_to_file);
```

This return nothing. Neither Success nor error.

Comment: seems that this plugin is no longer maintened, try this one https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#0.8.2

Comment: I tried that too. but not success.

Comment: @Owais is your device ready event fired properly??

Comment: Yes. Also i am send email on click event. can u give me contact number/email/skype etc.